# Socket connected but doesn't have Remote EndPoint

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, websocket

I'm trying to use generic IP socket objects in .NET. Connecting one of my sockets to another one and sending a few ping-pong messages works just fine.

But now I've implemented a server socket and somehow managed to create Schrödinger's socket.

The server socket handles the incoming connection request just fine, but the connecting socket seems to be connected when I check once but doesn't even have a RemoteEndpoint - though is showing "Connected = true" and it's disconnected when I check the 2nd time.

All sockets are initialized using this function:

```
private void initSocket() {

    if (_socket != null) {

        _socket.Dispose();
    }

    _socket = new Socket(_ownIP.AddressFamily, _socketType, _protocolType);
    _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(_ownIP, _ownPort));
}
```

The _socketType is Stream and the _protocolType is Tcp in this case.

The connect function:

```
 public bool connect(string ip, int port, int retries = 3) {

        if (_isWaiting) {

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't connect, when the socket is already waiting for clients.");
        }

        _wasWaiting = false;

        initSocket();

        _otherIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        _otherPort = port;
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(_otherIP, _otherPort);

        for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {

            try {

                IAsyncResult result = _socket.BeginConnect(endpoint, null, null);
                bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(_connectTimeout, true);

                if (_socket.Connected) {

                    _socket.EndConnect(result);
                    _isConnected = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else {

                    _socket.EndConnect(result);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e) {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The server uses this wait function to accept more clients:

```
private void wait() {

        while (_isWaiting) {

            try {

                _socket.Listen(1);
                var newSocket = _socket.Accept();
                var newClient = new IPSocket(newSocket, _socketType, _protocolType, new MessageReceivedDelegate(clientReceivedMessage), true);
                
                _clients.Add(newClient.PartnerIP + ":" + newClient.PartnerPort, newClient);
                clientConnected(newClient.PartnerIP, newClient.PartnerPort);

                while (true) {

                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex) {

                //Need to find out which one is thrown when no client for accepting available
                if (ex.ErrorCode == 2) {


                }

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            catch {

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

The newSocket variable is connected at first and has a valid RemoteEndpoint, but the socket that's connected doesn't route back to newSocket.

I thought that maybe the connection resets when the server socket tries to accept new sockets, so I added the infinite wait loop - which didn't help.

So why does the connecting socket not have any RemoteEndpoint? (it's shown as null)

---

Since people usually recommend to accept the connection, handle data, close connection:
I want to keep the connection alive and I have to - not doing this is at the time not a solution that I'd consider.

Comment: What does `initSocket();` do?

Comment: @ekke I added the initSocket function to the question